# Model passed to a partial view is null upon form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views, model-binding

I have the following model:

```
@model SmartSEOModel

public class SmartSEOModel
{
    public SmartSEOSettingsModel SmartSEOSettingsModel { get; set; }

    public SEOTemplateModel SEOTemplateModel { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I have a partial view which I call like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    some razor code here

    <div id="pnlSmartSEO">

        @Html.Partial(ViewNames.SmartSEOController_SEOTemplate, Model.SEOTemplateModel)

    </div>
}
```

In the partial view there are some form fields bound to the SEOTemplateModel.
The problem is that when I receive the SmartSEOModel in my HttpPost action, the SEOTemplateModel is null. As if the SEOTemplateModel has been passed by copying it to the partial view.

Please advise why this is and how to workaround it.

Many thanks

My partial view looks like this:

```
@Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("SmartSEO").Items(x =>
{
    x.Add().Text(T("Admin.SmartSEO").Text).Content(GetSmartSEOUI().ToHtmlString()).Selected(true);
})

@helper GetSmartSEOUI()
{
@(Html.LocalizedEditor<SEOTemplateModel, SEOTemplateLocalizedModel>("SmartSEO-Localized",
    @<table class="adminContent">
        <tr>
            <td class="adminTitle">
                @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Locales[item].CategoryTitleSEOTemplate):
            </td>
            <td class="adminData">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Locales[item].CategoryTitleSEOTemplate)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>,
    @<table class="adminContent">
        <tr>
            <td class="adminTitle">
                @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.CategoryTitleSEOTemplate):
            </td>
            <td class="adminData">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryTitleSEOTemplate)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
))
}
```

My HttpPost action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Configure(SmartSEOModel smartSEOModel)
    {
        var seoTemplate = SEOTemplateService.GetSEOTemplateById(smartSEOModel.SEOTemplateModel.Id);

        if(seoTemplate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("No SEOTemplate found with Id {0}", smartSEOModel.SEOTemplateModel.Id));
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Configure");
        }

        SettingService.SaveSetting(smartSEOModel.SmartSEOSettingsModel.ToEntity());
        seoTemplate = smartSEOModel.SEOTemplateModel.ToEntity(seoTemplate);
        SEOTemplateService.UpdateSEOTemplate(seoTemplate);
        UpdateLocales(seoTemplate, smartSEOModel.SEOTemplateModel);

        //activity log
        CustomerActivityService.InsertActivity("EditSEOTemplate", LocalizationService.GetResource("ActivityLog.EditSEOTemplate"));

        SuccessNotification(LocalizationService.GetResource("SevenSpikes.NopSmartSEO.Admin.SEOTemplate.Notifications.SEOTemplateEdited"));

        return View("SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.SmartSEO.Views.Configure", smartSEOModel);
    }
```

Comment: can you post the partial html too?

Comment: Is there a form within the partial view? 
Are you using jQueryUI Dialogs within that view?

Comment: Could you post the forms partial view and the post action code?

Comment: On this line: var seoTemplate = SEOTemplateService.GetSEOTemplateById(smartSEOModel.SEOTemplateModel.Id);   smartSEOModel.SEOTemplateModel is null.

Comment: Please note that this will work if it was in the main view not in a partial one. I cannot use it in the main view however for technical reasons which are note related to this post

Comment: Can you try passing the entire Model to the partial instead of just the Model.SEOTemplateModel? You would need to update the @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryTitleSEOTemplate) to include SEOTemplateModel in the partial. You could also look into creating a custom model binder.

Comment: I cannot pass it because the Html helper is bound to the model of the view and the Html.LocalizedEditor expects a certain type of model.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase you don't have a form within your partial view, it will not persist the data. Try using `@Html.EditorFor` instead of `@Html.Partial`.

So your main view would look like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    some razor code here

    <div id="pnlSmartSEO">

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SEOTemplateModel)

    </div>
}
```

You would then need to move your partial view into a template. Rename your partial view to  `EditorTemplates\SEOTemplateModel.cshtml` and place it in the same location where your main view is.

You will also need to make your template strongly typed: `@model [namespace].SEOTemplateModel`