# Partial View returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post, model, null, partial-views

Been racking my brains on this one for awhile. I have a view and a partial view. Both use the same model - tried using Viewmodels but ran into the same problem. The partial view contains user info like name, address, phone, etc. The view has a drop down menu with some text boxes. When I insert partial view and click submit my partial values are null. However, if I create a view without dropdown, I can display partial data to page, and I can even POST and save to database. The issue is when I combine the drop down (View) and Partial View data. even if they use the same model.

My Model is below

```
public class user
{
    public string uFirstName { get; set; }
    public string uLastName { get; set; }
    public string uPhoneNumb { get; set; }
    public string uAddress { get; set; }
    public string uEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string degProg { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CatList { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Please select")]
    public int CatId { get; set; }
    public string CatName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*Question Required")]
    public string questDetail { get; set; } //qt table
    public string courseNum { get; set; } //qt table
    public string assignNum { get; set; } //qt table

}
```

Here's my partial view. In my repository I am not using a List(ToList()) but instead FirstOrDefault() to get data.

```
@model LibraryMVC4.Models.user
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.uFirstName) @*Just checking to see if data can display*@

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.uFirstName)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.uLastName)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.degProg)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.uEmailAddress)
```

Here's my View with the drop down list and textboxes and partialview reference.

```
@model LibraryMVC4.Models.user
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserInfoPost", "AskLib", new { Model.CatId }.ToString(),                           

 FormMethod.Post))
{

 @Html.Partial("_userInfo") //Partial View Reference


 @("Category of your question: ") @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CatId, new      
 SelectList(Model.CatList, "Value", "Text"), "--Please Select--")

<span style="color:red;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CatId)</span>
<br/><br />
<p>Course Number: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.courseNum)</p>

<p>Activity Number: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.assignNum)</p>
<br />


<p>Please type your question into the box below.</p>

<span style="color: red;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.questDetail)</span><br />

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.questDetail, new { style = "width: 500px; height: 200px;" })
<br />


<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

Here's my controller HTTPPOST method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UserInfoPost(user _objResponse)
    {
        var UserInfo = new quest_tb

        {
            user_id = "XXXXXXX",
            u_first_name = _objResponse.uFirstName,
            u_last_name = _objResponse.uLastName,
            deg_prog = _objResponse.degProg,
            email_address = _objResponse.uEmailAddress,
            q_detail = _objResponse.questDetail,
            cat_desc = _objResponse.CatId,
            course_num = _objResponse.courseNum,
            assign_num = _objResponse.assignNum,
            date_time = DateTime.Now

        };

        _libEntity.quest_tb.AddObject(UserInfo);
        _libEntity.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("../");
    }
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I have covered everything from viewmodels, automapper, PartialViews, even EditorFields/EditorTemplates (I am using _layout), so I am not sure what I am missing. Should be simple. Thanks.

Comment: Does your `View` have a `@model` statement?  Could you include it?

Comment: Added @model statement.

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be a comma between `new { Model.CatId }.ToString()` and `FormMethod.Post`?

Comment: Added the comma. Yes, it's there. Formatting issue in the WYSIWYG.

Comment: I assume you've tried `@Html.Partial("_userInfo", Model)`?

Comment: Yes. Tried that. Tried just about everything for the last couple of days. In webforms this is a cinch.

Comment: Pardon the basic nature of this question, but I'm trying to be thorough: does the generated HTML for the partial view differ between the view-with-dropdown and view-without-dropdown?

Comment: No. Again, view-w/o-dropdown will display user info.

Comment: What's strange is that I can print out message from partial view just not the user info stuff, which means there something definitely wrong with my partial.

Comment: OK, this is a stupid-sounding, basic question, but I can't see all your code, so I have to ask:  Are you actually passing a populated `user` object to the view in your controller?  No offense meant, I just see lots of people asking MVC questions and in a lot of cases it turns out they didn't do that, just instantiated the view with the parameterless constructor.

Comment: Also, is the following Q+A of any help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490679/model-passed-to-a-partial-view-is-null-upon-form-submit